# Python: json serialization error on object instantiation

Tags: python, json, django

I have this simple python class

```
class CustomOAuth(object):

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, scope, state=None):
        """
        args:
            client_id : myapp client id
            client_secret: myapp client secret
            state : random string
        """
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.state = state
        self.RESPONSE_TYPE = "code"
        self.GRANT_TYPE_CODE = "authorization_code"
        self.GRANT_TYPE_TOKEN = "refresh_token"
        self.AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://www.myapp.com/oauth/authorize/"
        self.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.myapp.com/oauth/access_token/"
        #self.SCOPE = "scope:public scope:user:profile scope:location scope:vehicle:profile scope:vehicle:events scope:trip"
        self.scope = scope

    def __repr__(self):
        return "CustomOAuth: {'client_id': %s, 'client_secret': %s}" % (self.client_id, self.client_secret)

    def __str__(self):
        return "CustomOAuth: {'client_id': %s, 'client_secret': %s}" % (self.client_id, self.client_secret)
```

While instantiating the above class from a view of Django 
throws error although from python shell it works fine:

```
oauth = CustomOAuth(client_id=settings.API_KEY, client_secret=settings.SECRET_KEY, scope=setttings.SCOPE)
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError:

CustomOAuth: {'client_id': XXXXX, 'client_secret': YYYY} is not JSON serializable
```

What could be the possible issue ?

**Error Stacktrace**

Traceback:

```
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  204.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  42.                     request.session.save()
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  58.             session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in encode
  89.         serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
File "/home/naveen/ENV/automaticfleet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py" in dumps
  89.         return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  250.         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in encode
  207.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  270.         return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in default
  184.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /user/authenticate
Exception Value: CustomOAuth: {'client_id': 9f44cdcd26eacbf988ee, 'client_secret': d3d4cfe432ba90eccac276ad395e76f9db1ab3fc, 'scope': scope:trip} is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: That error isn't happening on instantiation. Please show the full traceback and the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  please refer to edited post

Comment: That's not helpful. For a start, please don't post screenshots of text; secondly, that is not the full traceback. Please click on the link on that page helpfully marked "switch to copy-and-paste view", and paste the full traceback code here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for guiding me , post now has full stacktrace.

Comment: Whatever is happening here expects you to return a valid json from `__repr__` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you were right , that error was coming when i was storing the object into the session, i have resolved it by using SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer' in settings.py file